# GPO script policies not working on Windows 10 1809

Tags: windows-10, group-policy

It seems group policies under Local Group Policy Editor>Computer configuration>Administrative Templates>System>Scripts are not working in Windows 10 version 1809. Back in 1803 they worked perfectly fine.

I can confirm that they can be set and the changes are shown in the registry (Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System) but the system does not care about them and uses default settings.

More importantly i want the "Specify maximum wait time for group policy scripts" to work since it prevents my PC restarting or shutting down unless 600 seconds (aka 10 minutes which is the default value - which is a ridiculously long value and Microsoft should use a more appropriate default value like 5 seconds) of uptime has passed, as this PC is under a domain which is not always accessible as i am not always connected to the domain network.

Back in 1803 i had this policy set to 1 second to prevent this issue. Now none of the policy settings there work anymore.

Anyone found a fix or should i downgrade back to 1803?

Comment: What does rsop show for this value? Btw, login and startup scripts are bad practice. If you are going to use them there are ways to avoid problems for mobile users. The problem is not Microsoft or the default policies. The problem is how things have been implemented. 1 second would be ridiculous as none of your scripts would have a chance to finish. Considering login/logoff/startup/shutdown scripts are typically used to configure things and install software, 10 minutes is perfectly reasonable and often I increase it to 30 minutes in this situation.

Comment: I'm not using any scripts, neither my domain. It's just this stupid Microsoft setting which forces the system to check for scripts if you are a domain user even though you might not be connected to the domain network at that time. In Rsop everything shows fine, however i just connected today to the domain network and did a gpupdate /force which might have fixed it somehow. I need to test.

Comment: I think you might be misunderstanding what the problem is. Where are you getting your information from? If there aren’t any scripts defined in policy then the computer is not waiting for scripts. That is probably why you think the policy isn’t working.

Comment: i just updated the gpo policy and the changes took effect so the problem is fixed.